# C# ASP.Net - ListBox - onSelectedIndexChanged causes error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, listbox

I am quite new to ASP.Net and I am trying to create a `DataList` on one of the pages, feed it from code behind and then trigger method when `onSelectedIndexChanged` occurs. I am not sure if its relevant, but I am using master page.

Just to make it simple I removed all the unnecessary stuff.

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" 
 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem>Chosen One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>wannabe Chosen One</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
```

This is my method `ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
 private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 //the new chosen one should swallow some blue pill here... 
 }
```

However, when I run the app I am getting the error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061:
>   'aaldetails_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged'
>   and no extension method 'ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'aaldetails_aspx' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is going on? And why?
What am I doing wrong?
(well... my wife'd say "what am I actually doing right" is a better question).

Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you change `private` to `protected`?

Comment: Errrrrr... Now it is one of those moments when I seriously consider quietly deleting this question, selling computer, using the earned money to buy some sheep and move to the mountains. IT WORKS!!!! THANKS!!!!! I am going to read and learn about it again... Such a mistake. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like wiring up the selected change event to code behind has some problem, did you check if the designer.cs sometimes visual studio does not create the definition for the controller at all. Try closing all instances of VS and reopen your project.

Answer (score -1):

try it in form load and put your codes in

if(!isPostBack)
{
//your codes

}